# Rsync combined with FIND and mtime

Tags: linux, find, rsync

I've been thinking about how I could copy files that are 0-30 days old with different file types with `rsync`, `find` and `mtime`.

The`find` syntax below works, but I do not get it to work with `rsync`.

```
rsync \ --files-from=<(find . -type f \( -name "*.X" -or -name "*.x1" \) -mtime -30) user@x.x.x.x:/where/to/put/files
```

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "no success".  What precisely happens or doesn't happen?  Are any files transferred or are none?  What output does rsync generate? 
 What error messages do you see?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [unix.se]. Two quick clarifications that I think would help getting a good answer: (1) Is the backslash between `rsync` and `--files-from` a copy/paste error? Second, what does "no success" mean — do you get an error message? Does it just not copy the files? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for bad explanation, what I mean is that I dont get it to work. When it comes to the rsync syntax im confused if Im supposed to use the \ or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you use add a SRC argument (the `.` as source directory):

```
rsync --files-from=<(find . -type f \( -name "*.X" -o -name "*.x1" \) -mtime -30) . user@x.x.x.x:/where/to/put/files
```

Comment: Hi @Freddy Thanks, we are getting closer to make it work. When I run it now i get the following:  rsync: change_dir “/my/dir/that/has/a/name//\#342\#200\#224files-from=/dev/fd" failed: No such file or directory (2)
skipping directory .
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]      -But when I run the find syntax in the same directory I find all of them which i want to copy

Comment: I had a mistake in my answer. If you copied this example, make sure `--files-from` starts with two minus characters `--`. Hope this fixes the error.

Comment: No problem Freddy. Still no luck.                                                           
user@x.x.x.x’s password:
rsync: change_dir “/xx/xx/xx//\#342\#200\#224files-from=/dev/fd" failed: No such file or directory (2)
skipping directory .
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]

Comment: Hmm. Does your target directory exist? If your target dir is `/a/b/c`, then at least `/a/b` should exist.

Comment: Yes it does, it was just a typo from me.. Now I get: rsync: mkstemp "/aa/bb/cc/.my.file failed: Permission denied (13)

Comment: @pettanx95 It seems the user has no write permissions on that directory. Maybe try a sync to `/tmp` first and check if that works. Then make sure the user has write permissions on the target directory.

Comment: Did go with the easy way... Enabled the root user and used that one :D Thx for the help Freddy!